# Windows Server 2022 Task Scheduler runs twice from time to time

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2022

I created a scheduled task on Windows Server 2022 which runs every 3 hours. Basically this task reads some data from database, transforms the data into an HTML email and sends email automatically. None of the tasks run so far had failed but at a specific timing it is running twice.

[image: This is how I set the trigger]

I deleted the scheduled task and re-created a new one but the problem is re-occurring.